# How to efficiently filter repeating values of s and d from a table of (s,d) pairs, keeping only smallest (s,d) pairs

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my test case

```
CREATE TABLE matches AS
        SELECT 1 s, 2 d
  UNION SELECT 1, 3 -- (1,2) preferred
  UNION SELECT 2, 2 -- (1,2) preferred
  UNION SELECT 2, 3
  UNION SELECT 3, 3 -- (2,3) preferred
  UNION SELECT 3, 4;
```

I want to filter this table and keep each s or d value only once, prioritizing smallest (s,d) pairs. The result should be `(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)`.
How to do this efficiently?

I tried the query below but it only works if d values associated to different s values don't overlap

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT
     *,
     row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY s ORDER BY d) rs,
     row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY d ORDER BY s) rd
    FROM matches
   ) t
WHERE rd = rs;
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: the logic for your expected results is not clear, it seemed to be based on the lowest D for a given S, but the results then include (2,3) instead of (2,2)

Comment: Why is (1,2) preferred over (2,2)?

Comment: thanks for the comments, I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Andrew, (1,2) is mutually exclusive with (2,2) because they share the same d=2. (1,2) is preferred because (1,2)<(2,2)

Comment: @JohnConde is it ok to duplicate the question and use different tags then? because it would be interesting to know how it could be done in different DBMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your intentions correctly, you can do this by copying the table to a new (possibly temporary) table which has UNIQUE indexes on `s` and `d` and using `INSERT IGNORE` to copy the data:

```
CREATE TABLE matches AS
        SELECT 1 s, 2 d
  UNION SELECT 1, 3 -- (1,2) preferred
  UNION SELECT 2, 2 -- (1,2) preferred
  UNION SELECT 2, 3
  UNION SELECT 3, 3
  UNION SELECT 3, 4;

CREATE TABLE matches2 (s INT, d INT);
ALTER TABLE matches2 ADD UNIQUE KEY (s), ADD UNIQUE KEY(d);

INSERT IGNORE INTO matches2 
SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY s, d;

SELECT * FROM matches2
```

Output:

```
s   d
1   2
2   3
3   4
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes using a temporary table then inserting is a possible solution, it is the method I'm using right now (with left joins instead of indexes), but it seems very inefficient.

Comment: I think an index is probably more efficient than a left join, but it would be interesting to see stats. The difficulty with your problem is that if (for example) (1,3) didn't get knocked out by (1,2), it would knock out (2,3), but because (1,3) did get knocked out, (2,3) makes it into the output. So you really need to have state somewhere that you can look at, and a temporary table is a good way of having that. The other alternative is probably a stored procedure.

Comment: your method seems better than mine, because I have to insert repeatedly in a stored procedure when using left joins. And yes the difficulty is to keep track of accepted values, I am wondering if window functions wouldn't allow that more efficiently

Comment: You might be right about window functions. I'm not sure they can maintain enough state though. I'll certainly be interested to see if someone comes up with a solution using them.

Comment: @klarezz I'm curious, did you ever figure out a better way of doing this?

Comment: Nope, I'm still using a temporary table. I will keep you updated if I find a better way.